# System always hangs shortly after login on 2009 macbook pro

Tags: macbook

I recently installed Elementary on my 2009 MacBook Pro. Every time I start up and log in the system becomes unresponsive within minutes (maybe even within seconds.) The mouse continues to work and I can move the cursor, but not click anything. After several minutes one of the actions I have tried happens then it hangs again. For example, a new tab opens in Epiphany, but it is otherwise unresponsive. Eventually I have to shut it down (hard reboot, or get to a Terminal and shutdown more gracefully - I think that was CTRL+ALT+F1 that worked, although I tried lots of shortcut combinations and one of them seemed to work but only after several minutes.) It happens even if only Epiphany is running. One time I noticed blue dots underneath a couple of the applications in the dock, but a red dot under the appcenter one. That wasn't true every time it happened.

The system is not usable as it is, I would like to know any troubleshooting tips anyone can give me as I need to figure out whether this is fixable, or a hardware problem with the mbp (I had a suspicion of something not right with the hardware before install because it didn't work with later versions of MAC OS, but it ran OS X Snow Leopard fine.)

Answer (score 0):

OK thank you to all who read this, I have now found the problem. It seems that starting Epiphany causes the system to hang. I had though that as that was the browser that came with the installation it should be OK but on my 2009 MacBook Pro it causes instability. I'm now using Firefox and that's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a lot of system-wide crashes using Epiphany with the Nouveau drivers.
The proprietary Nvidia drivers work much better, but on older Macbooks such as yours you will likely need to be booting in legacy BIOS compatibility mode for the graphics drivers to work correctly.
See my answer regarding a 2010 Macbook [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/26397/20782) for more details.